# Add image to Word document, like drag and drop

Tags: ms-word, vsto, transparency

I need to be able to insert an image in a Word document via my .Net (VB) VSTO Word AddIn.

The problem is that I need it inserted so it ends up the same way as if a user had used 'Drag & Drop' to insert the image, instead of the 'Insert Picture' toolbar button.

Normally I do it like this:

```
wdRange.InlineShapes.AddPicture(imagePath, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
```

But this replicates the 'Insert Picture' buttons behaviour.

The reason I need to replicate the drag & drop method, is that the pictures react differently when printed in some cases.

I can replicate this by inserting a large colored rectangle in the document header, and placing the image in the document body, so it ends up on top of the colored rectangle.
If the inserted image has transparency (like many logos do) it will end up with a dark background instead of being completely transparent, when printed, in some cases.
(I have not found out the exact situation required to replicate the problem, but it seems to require a certain combination of printer drivers being either PCL or PS.)

And just to make it harder to debug this issue, it is not visible when printing to a PDF printer, it only seems occurs on paper. And only in somewhat rare configurations. It can happen on both color and B/W printers, both new (<1 year) and old printers.

Scanned example of the above mentioned scenario when printed, with two images placed over the colored rectangle.
One image (with dark background) is inserted with the 'Insert Picture' button, the other (with correct transparency) via drag & drop.
Both images are inserted by using the same .png-file. (One is scaled a bit different than the other though, but I have tested thoroughly and scaling or moving the image does not affect the problem.)
[image: Problem example]

I tried recording a macro while dragging & dropping the image, but nothing was recorded :-\

As an alternate solution, perhaps there is some property of the inserted image that can be changed, to ensure it acts like the one inserted via drag & drop?
That would be perfectly acceptable!

Note: I cannot replicate this issue on any of the 8 printers I have available in-house, and only experience this issue on-location with a few (large) customers. *So testing a proposed solution might unfortunately take some time* :-(

*Update*
It turns out that I can only replicate the picture with the correct transparent background when using Drag & Drop from Windows 10 to Word 2016.
Windows 7 generates a different result, so my previous tests (made in Windows 7) were invalid.

The two image elements (one inserted via 'Insert Picture', one via Drag & Drop) looks different when selected in Word.
The wrong picture ('Insert Picture') has white selection markers, as shown here:

[image]

The right picture (Drag & Drop from Windows 10) has grey selection markers, as shown here:

[image]

The image I used for the tests is here ('Transparent.gif'. same image file for both pictures)

[image]

I examined the OpenXML Markup for each image, and they are very different.
The wrong picture ends up like a `w:drawing` element:

```
<w:drawing>
    <wp:anchor distT="0" distB="0" distL="114300" distR="114300" simplePos="0" relativeHeight="251662336" behindDoc="0" locked="0" layoutInCell="1" allowOverlap="1">
        <wp:simplePos x="0" y="0"/>
        <wp:positionH relativeFrom="margin">
            <wp:align>left</wp:align>
        </wp:positionH>
        <wp:positionV relativeFrom="paragraph">
            <wp:posOffset>817245</wp:posOffset>
        </wp:positionV>
        <wp:extent cx="3048000" cy="647700"/>
        <wp:effectExtent l="0" t="0" r="0" b="0"/>
        <wp:wrapSquare wrapText="bothSides"/>
        <wp:docPr id="9" name="Billede 9"/>
        <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
            <a:graphicFrameLocks xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" noChangeAspect="1"/>
        </wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
        <a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
            <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                <pic:pic xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                    <pic:nvPicPr>
                        <pic:cNvPr id="9" name="Transparent.gif"/>
                        <pic:cNvPicPr/>
                    </pic:nvPicPr>
                    <pic:blipFill>
                        <a:blip r:embed="rId1">
                            <a:extLst>
                                <a:ext uri="{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}">
                                    <a14:useLocalDpi xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main" val="0"/>
                                </a:ext>
                            </a:extLst>
                        </a:blip>
                        <a:stretch>
                            <a:fillRect/>
                        </a:stretch>
                    </pic:blipFill>
                    <pic:spPr>
                        <a:xfrm>
                            <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
                            <a:ext cx="3048000" cy="647700"/>
                        </a:xfrm>
                        <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                            <a:avLst/>
                        </a:prstGeom>
                    </pic:spPr>
                </pic:pic>
            </a:graphicData>
        </a:graphic>
        <wp14:sizeRelH relativeFrom="page">
            <wp14:pctWidth>0</wp14:pctWidth>
        </wp14:sizeRelH>
        <wp14:sizeRelV relativeFrom="page">
            <wp14:pctHeight>0</wp14:pctHeight>
        </wp14:sizeRelV>
    </wp:anchor>
</w:drawing>
```

The right picture ends up as a `v:shape` with a lot less markup:

```
<v:shape id="_x0000_s2049" type="#_x0000_t75" style="position:absolute;margin-left:.3pt;margin-top:0;width:240pt;height:51pt;z-index:251661312;mso-position-horizontal:absolute;mso-position-horizontal-relative:text;mso-position-vertical:bottom;mso-position-vertical-relative:text;mso-width-relative:page;mso-height-relative:page">
    <v:imagedata r:id="rId2" o:title="Transparent"/>
    <w10:wrap type="square"/>
</v:shape>
```

So far I have not been able to recreate the latter via VBA or VB.NET (via an VSTO AddIn).

If someone can figure that out, I'm convinced the problem is solved.

Here's a link to the sample document I'm working with, the top picture prints correctly, the bottom picture prints with a darker background color (on some printers, unfortunately not any of mine.)
[Simple-test.docx](https://www.dropbox.com/s/igjesj4t3p2wuh3/Simpel-test.docx?dl=0)
(Everything is placed in the page header, since according to my tester, this might be a factor.)

Comment: Try comparing the xml of the two images. If you can identify what is different perhaps you can then add that into your solution.

Comment: Interesting idea. You wouldn't happen to have an easy way to access this XML? Or is renaming the document to .zip, unpacking it and then examining the content really the easiest way?

Comment: I use 7Zip as there is no need to rename the file. I assign Visual Studio Code as the Editor in 7Zip to examine/edit the xml. If you copy the xml for each image into new files in VS Code you can then use the built-in comparison tool to show you the differences.

Comment: Comparing the XML for the two pictures, I notice that one has this node: `<pic:spPr>` where the other has this one: `<pic:spPr bwMode="auto">` - that is the difference that mostly seem to stand out. So far searching for a description of *bwMode* or how to manually change it, has not given me any results :-(

Comment: Hmm Just noticed some other XML that's only present in one of them: `<a:noFill/><a:ln><a:noFill/></a:ln>` This could easily be related, since it refers to fill of some kind. And the problem relates to a background that appears to be filled. Unfortunately searches once again renders no interesting results for *noFill*, though I suspect it might be related to some property related to `ActiveDocument.InlineShapes([index]).Fill`, I just can't find anything that's different there at the moment.

Comment: In case anyone might be interested in the XML, I made it available here: https://pastebin.com/Qu2t9q50

Comment: Have you identified which image is the one you dragged and dropped? I suspect it will be the one with the extra xml. Have you tried adding  <a:noFill/> to the xml for the other image? Does that fix the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151614/discussion-between-gertsen-and-m4o-tim).

Comment: I added some new info to the bottom of the question, hope this might help move forward. For now it seems the Chat has gone missing though :-/

Answer (score 1):

To set the `<a:noFill/>` you need to set the Fill properties of the shape. Something similar to the following should do it, where `inlShape` is an object set to your inserted image:

```
inlShape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = -1
inlShape.Fill.Visible = False
```

Note that it is necessary to set both the ForeColor and the Visible properties. Setting just one of them will not produce the result you require.

Comment: Very nice. I tried these settings myself, but didn't get the same results - but I always tried one setting at a time, so that explains it. I'm still awaiting feedback before I can know what works.